# how to find function boundaries in binary code

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I see that binary translation is usually trace-based. Is it because one can not get the  boundaries of functions? Is there function label in binary code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no trivial answer to this. You could search for `ret` instructions, but they are no guarantee that they are function boundaries as you could return from the middle of a function.

Searching for stuff like

```
mov   ebp, esp
```

will work to some extent, but again, it's no guarantee.

Some compilers (most notably the Intel Compiler), will move branched blocks to *after* the function ends, and jump back into the function...

Comment: It is easy to get the function label info from LLVM binary code. Why doesn't machine code include function label info?

Comment: But this isn't LLVM. It's a fully-compiled binary. (at least that's what I'm assuming...)

Answer (score 0):

What does trace-based mean? The essential answer to your question is no, there is no function label in machine code. There are probably patterns specific to each compiler you could look for and you could also use the executable format to find entry points into public functions in the code. But these days compilers can do whole-program optimizations that blur out the concept of a function at the machine code level.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for finding the begin and ending addresses of C functions is to print out a memory map and scan for the start of the function.  Many compilers will specify the function length in the memory map.

Some compilers provide `#pragma` or preprocessing keywords to allow you to assign a function to a specific address.

Sorry, but the C language only provides the starting address of functions; not their lengths.

Comment: If one knows the starting addresses of all functions, it is easy to get the lengths, right?

Comment: No, the C language does not provide facilities for getting function lengths. One must consult the map file and the linker instruction file. There is no requirement for the linker to place functions contiguously, nor in the same space; one function could be in SRAM, another in ROM.