# Is there any way to get the size of a c function?

Tags: c

I want to know if there is a way to get the size of c function in memory at runtime.

I've used this code but it's not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t[10];
    char c;
    offsetof(t, p);
    p: 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `offsetof` is for structs. Why do you need this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is generally no. You can't. One reason is because functions are not necessarily contiguous in memory. So they don't have a "size". Sometimes, compilers (namely ICC) will make jumps out of the function to a remote part of the binary and jump back in.

See a related question here:

[how to find function boundaries in binary code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354507/how-to-find-function-boundaries-in-binary-code/7354552#7354552)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing data with code, the variable `t` is not related to the function `main` in terms of memory address. `t` is stored on the stack, `main` is in the code section.

As for getting the size of the function, there is no standard way to get the size. If you're willing to write a disassembler and static code analysis you might get a rough idea of the size, but even that is not trivial as the final `ret` instruction may not be the last instruction of the function, say you return from inside a loop.

You could analyse the compiler / linker output data (PDBs, map files, etc).

But then, why do you need to know?

Comment: Sometimes you may want to relocate a function, that is, copy it to some other location in memory. At other times you may want to change page protection for the code contained in a function. Or to encrypt/decrypt a function. You need to know the size to do these. All of these aren't typical manipulations with code.

Comment: @Alex: if you need to do any of those things you're (in effect) a "dynamic linker", in which case you need the extra implementation-specific information that dynamic linkers use, and that the questioner makes no mention of having.

Comment: @Alex: To relocate a function would require finding all the places that called the function and updating the call address. I can't think of any operating system where you can do this. Even GameBoy cartridges didn't do this (everything was paged and used relative offsets from page base so they never changed). Encryption - that's usually done to the whole executable (like a self extracting zip).

Comment: @Skizz: you may not need to find places that the function is called from directly. It may be intended to be always executed from a different location, in which case you only need to copy it there making sure it can work there (doing the necessary address fix ups or whatever it takes, unless it's guaranteed to be position-independent).

Answer (score 1):

You can examine a disassembly.  Disassemblers are available for most environments, and often the compiler itself can generate them from the source for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it done, but I can't really imagine why you would need it. The thing to remember is if you subtract two pointers, it yields a ptrdiff_t, which if added to the first pointer would yield the second. This works for function pointers! So how about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("main is %u bytes long\n", (unsigned) (metamain - main));
    return 0;
}

void metamain (void) {
}
```