# Size of function in MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get the size of a c function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992420/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-size-of-a-c-function)

I need to determine the byte size of a c function at runtime. I am working with MSVC and I can use any technique that this compiler offers.

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I could only find people saying "no, its not possible". Still, maybe I have overseen a solution. If this is the case please point me.

Comment: What do you mean by "size of function"?

Comment: You're correct; this has been asked a lot.  So there's not really a reason to ask it again!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Except that he's being enough more specific (MS VC) that this one probably has an answer, where most of the others don't.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing MSVC splitting apart functions the way that ICC does. So this may actually have an answer.

Comment: If there is an answer ... where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this should be possible. A little bit of how you proceed will depend on how accurate a result you need. If some possible inaccuracy is acceptable, my first choice would be [`SymEnumSymbols`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680718.aspx). You supply a call-back function that gets called for each symbol fitting the filter you specify. Your callback function will be given the name and a calculated (guessed) size for each symbol. When you get to the right symbol, you've got the size it guesses/calculates for your function (though beware: it can also say the size is 0, so you'll probably have to do some testing to get a good idea of how well it's likely to work for what you want).

A little testing indicates that this *seems* to be fairly accurate in the case of functions (I was a bit worried that this might be a case where it would return 0). Note that you do normally want to build with debug information to use this (exporting the function(s) you care about might be sufficient though).

Another possibility (though probably more complex) would be to use `#pragma code_seg` to put that function you care about in a section by itself with a unique section name, then walk the PE file to find that size of that section.

Comment: Dont you think that this is just possible when compiling with debug info?

Comment: @Erik: As mentioned in the answer, simply exporting the function is probably sufficient (testing indicates that it is).

Comment: Like this: __declspec( dllimport ) ?

Answer (score 4):

In general, it generates code the sane way, in the order in which functions appear in the source code.  So the size is the address of the next function minus the address of the function.

There are however several ways in which that won't work out well.  First is the incremental link option, you'll get a value of 5.  Which is the size of a jmp instruction that jumps to the actual function.  These jumps are what allow the linker to replace code without completely re-linking the image, it simply appends code and patches the jump address.

And there's the optimizer of course.  You can't meaningfully talk about a function size anymore when it gets inlined.  You'll need __declspec(noinline).

Can be done, test the heck out of it and thoroughly comment the code so nobody will insert a function some day.  And if you are doing this to move code, be sure to remember that the compiler doesn't generate position-independent code and cannot patch relocations on that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested, compile from MSVC into .asm, then figure out the byte difference between function start label and a custom label at the end, calculate the difference between them. :) Typically, compilers don't generate an end of function label ... just the beginning.

You typically don't use this unless the functions need to be relocated in memory, and called!

Comment: Don't forget to bring your x86 assembly reference in order to find out each instruction size.

Comment: You don't do that.. :) Rather,

_putc:

…
ret

_endlabel:

extern int *putc, *endlabel;
size=(endlabel-putc);